# Prove $\det[D f (x)] \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, inverse-function-theorem

Let $U, V ⊆ \mathbb R^n$ be open sets and $f : U → V$ a differentiable bijection with a differentiable inverse. Show that $\det[D f (x)] \neq 0$ for any $x ∈ U$.

This shows that the converse of the Inverse Function Theorem holds, but how should I prove it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is invertible and say its inverse is $g$ then we see that
\begin{align}
g(f(x)) = x
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
Dg(f(x))Df(x) = 1.
\end{align}
Likewise, you have that
\begin{align}
f(g(y)) = y
\end{align}
where $x=g(y)$ and
\begin{align}
Df(g(y))Dg(y)=Df(x)Dg(f(x)) = 1.
\end{align}
Hence $Df(x)$ is invertible which means $\det [Df(x)] \neq 0$.

Comment: You can also just take the determinant of your second equation and use the fact that $\det$ is multiplicative.

Comment: @user7530 true.

Comment: @JackyChong Can you please show me the details of likewise? I did not get where is the y.

Comment: I used $x$ to indicate a point in $U$ and $y$ to indicate a point in $V$.